# Custom File upload Exception on CD server only "HttpPostedFileBase" is not marked as serializable

Tags: sitecore-forms

Getting the below exception when submitting a Sitecore Experience Form on the `CD server`. The form had the File Upload field which is Custom build.

A code snippet is also posted below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106191/discussion-on-question-by-paramjeet-sitecore-9-forms-custom-file-upload-except).

Comment: Please add the stack trace and code as text to your post vs using images. It will help you and this site by making the question more searchable.